# SQL no default value

Tags: sql, database

Hi everyone i am trying to make a game database for a score project, testing it out on SQL Fiddle and keep getting this error saying PlayerID has no default value, however this is auto incremented so i do not understand why?? any help would be appreciated.

```
CREATE TABLE tblPlayer (
  PlayerID INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
  UserName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  Password VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  Email VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  HighScore INT (50),
  AccountType BOOLEAN, 
  Status BOOLEAN,
  Country VARCHAR (50)
 );

CREATE TABLE tblGame (
  GameID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  Timeleft DECIMAL NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE tblMap (
   MapID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
   GameID INT,
   MineLocationXY VARCHAR(10),
   OneLocationXY VARCHAR(10),
   TwoLocationXY VARCHAR(10),
   ThreeLocationXY VARCHAR(10),
   FOREIGN KEY (GameID) REFERENCES tblGame (GameID)
);

CREATE TABLE tblPlayerGame (
    PlayerID INT NOT NULL,
    GameID INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (PlayerID,GameID),
    PlayerOneScore INT(50),
    PlayerTwoScore INT(50),
    FOREIGN KEY (PlayerID) REFERENCES tblPlayer (PlayerID),
    FOREIGN KEY (GameID) REFERENCES tblGame (GameID)
    );

CREATE TABLE tblPlayerClick (
    PlayerID INT,
    LocationX VARCHAR (10),
    LocationY VARCHAR (10),
    FOREIGN KEY (PlayerID) REFERENCES tblPlayer (PlayerID)
);

INSERT INTO tblPlayer (UserName,Password,Email,AccountType,Status,Country)
 VALUES ('Geoff22','password2016','Geoff@Email.com',TRUE, TRUE, 'New Zealand'),
        ('Steve1','password','steve@Email.com',False, TRUE, 'USA')   
;

INSERT INTO tblGame (TimeLeft) 
VALUES (120), (120)
;

INSERT INTO tblMap (MineLocationXY,OneLocationXY,TwoLocationXY,ThreeLocationXY)
VALUES ('X2,Y3','X6,Y8','X9,Y1','X1,Y3')
;

INSERT INTO tblPlayerClick (LocationX,LocationY)
VALUES ('X1','Y2')
;

INSERT INTO tblPlayerGame (PlayerOneScore,PlayerTwoScore)
VALUES (22,19)
;
```

Comment: Forgot to add its for a game similar to mine sweeper but with the optional of two player

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this `insert`:

```
INSERT INTO tblPlayerGame (PlayerOneScore,PlayerTwoScore)
    VALUES (22,19);
```

You have no values for `PlayerId` and `GameId`.  These are declared `NOT NULL` with no default values.

Hence, you are getting an error.

Comment: I see what your saying but both the PlayerID and GameID are being used for the composite key in this table and referencing back to there parent tables. So they should be getting the values from there?

Comment: @AaronLyall . . . No, that is not how foreign keys work.  The `foreign key` relationship means that you have to insert valid values into each row.